# Skype in Ubuntu creates 4 processes and comsumes a lot of RAM

Tags: skype, ram

I am using skype (skypeforlinux) in Ubuntu 16.04. I have noticed that when open 4 skype processes are active.

More specifically I have:

- 2 processes of `skypeforlinux` occupying approximately 162 and 52 MB respectively.
- 1 process with full command: `/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=zygote --no-sandbox` occupying 12 MB and finally
- 1 process with fully command `/usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=gpu-process --no-sandbox --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=9,27,84 --disable-gl-extensions....` (it has more than this) with 87 MB.

The final process also occupies 57MB of GPU memory according to `nvidia-smi`.

So, I have 4 processes summing up to 313 MB and I haven't even starting using skype yet. Is this normal behavior? Are all those processes necessary for the typical operation of skype? Could I kill some of them (I guess not but I am asking to be sure). Is there a way to reduce the memory footprint of skype anyway?

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. The Skype went through many changes in last years. The one most noticeable is that the developers disabled the old versions of Skype (including Smart TVs) and left only the most recent versions. There is no low resources version of Skype, when you are not counting the one for Android and other phone OS-es.

Below is the list of processes, when the Skype is idle on your computer.

[image: List of Skype processes when idle]

Comment: So, there aren't many I can do to save some RAM as I get it?

Comment: Not that I know at the moment.

Comment: If they are idle, the memory use is just VM, and much of that is shared with other processes, like the memory map of libc.  It does beg the question of why they do not use threads so they can share the VM and communicate through it!  The only benefit to multiple processes is that one might restart others if they die, and they can die individually.  What major IT org codes for failure, especially failure they can prevent?