# Skype taking too much virtual memory

Tags: skype, memory-usage

When starting skype under Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS it starts several processes. Two of them occupy 41.2GB and 32.6GB of virtual memory. Is that really needed? Are there files that can be deleted freeing that memory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your issue seems very similar to the following report: https://askubuntu.com/q/1088508/32664.